# Does weak convergence imply some kind of approximation?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, applications

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $x_n$ be a sequence in $X$ converging weakly to $x \in X$. Then can we say $x$ 'approximates' $x_n$ in some sense? This question is motivated from the homogenization theory. There one has a PDE of the form
\begin{equation}
A_\epsilon(u_\epsilon)=f_\epsilon,
\end{equation}
where $A_\epsilon$ is a linear partial differential operator. Here $\epsilon$ can represents the heterogeneity of the domain. Due to heterogeneity, this problems are numerically expensive.
Now suppose $u_\epsilon$ weakly converges to $u$ where $u$ is the unique solution of the following PDE
\begin{equation}
A(u)=f,
\end{equation}
for some suitable operator $A$ and a function $f$. Then can we say that $u$ is the approximation of $u_\epsilon$ in some sense?

Comment: It might help to know the Banach space in which you're considering weak convergence. In function spaces, you might get pointwise convergence (e.g. in $C[0, 1]$ under the $\infty$ norm).

Comment: I mean, sure, you can say anything you like, and usually "approximates" is just a synonym for "converges to", with the topology understood from context.  Usually what one wants to know is if some property is preserved from the approximation to the limit.  What property are you looking for here?

Comment: @user804886  Usually the space one has here is $L^2$.

Comment: @NateEldredge I want to approximate the integral and the space is $L^2$. If we have strong convergence then the 'approximation' is clear. But for the case of weak convergence , maybe we can choose suitable test fuction (e.g, 1 in a small domain and 0 outside). Then we can say that the integrals are approximated. Does it make  sense?

Comment: Not quite, I'm afraid.  You say $L^2$, but over what measure space?  If the measure is finite (e.g. a bounded domain with Lebesgue measure) then you certainly have $\int x_n \to \int x$ just by taking the test function 1.  If the measure is infinite then there is no reason to expect that $x_n$ or $x$ is integrable, so neither $\int x_n$ nor $\int x$ necessarily makes sense.

Comment: Usually the domain in this case is finite ( because the domain represents some part of composite material , for example). Also one is interested in local integral behaviour. So we can take a test function which is 1 in a small subset of the domain and zero outside.